# How do I use JS, JQuery to download or view a PDF after filling a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a page where users can view a PDF file, like a brochure. I would like them to fill a form first, where the information gets sent to an email and then the page redirects to opens the PDF.

Since I am not using any server side coding, I am using the `mailto:example@email.com` in the form `post` part to get the details.

How can I use JS, JQuery to download or view a PDF after filling a form?

**Update:** I was playing around and realized that using `mailto:` to post the form details opens the computer's email client, through which you have to manually click send. 
Meaning that the PDF can be viewed without actually receiving the details of who downloaded it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  Get Brochure
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
       aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">View Sample Brochure</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please fill out the form below first</p>
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="text/plain">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" Name="First Name" placeholder="First Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" Name="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Company" Name="Company" placeholder="Company" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usermail" Name="MailId" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- modal -->
```

Comment: you can pass my download() function a url and it will trigger a client-side download, as long as you can reach the url with ajax. https://github.com/rndme/download/

Comment: you need to use jspdf.js for pdf viewer or download. jspdf.js is available at https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: jspdf.js looks great. Is there an example out there on how to link the html form post to send the form input details and then redirect to an open PDF?

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF is at a known url, you can automate a click on a link to view or download it:

```js
function download (href) {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = href;
  anchor.download = true;
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  anchor.click();
}

download('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf');
```

Comment: If I use an `<a href="">`, how do I get the the form to post?

Comment: Two separate things. You’d post the form first.